# Prevent function from firing on page load with .hashchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hashchange

So I have a simple AJAX loading setup with the .hashchange event, as follows:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).hashchange( function(){
        $( "main" ).load( location.hash.substring(1) + ".html" , function() {  
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: $("main").offset().top
            }, 800);
        });
    });
    $(window).hashchange();
});
```

The ajax loaded content of the page ("main") is below a sizable navigation section, and when the hashchange event fires, the page scrolls down to the content section. Basically what I would like to know is how to prevent this scrolling function from firing on page load when there is no hash at the end of the current URL, or alternatively, only firing when an ajax function has completed. Thank you!

I am using Ben Alman's hashchange plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/